# Simulate a click on start button (at bots)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

Is it possible to simulate a click on the start button without saying `/start` ?

[image]

Comment: using a regular-user or bot? you can't do that as bot

Comment: I am using it as a regular user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This button simply sends a message with "/start" as the text to the bot, which can be done with [`client.send_message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message):

```py
client.send_message(bot, '/start')
```

If it has parameters add them after a space:

```py
client.send_message(bot, '/start argument')
```

Raw API also has [`messages.startBot`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/start_bot.html) which offers some more flexibility and I believe hides the start message.

Comment: Thank you! The `messages.startBot` request call works perfectly!